# Can I async UIImageJPEGRepresentation writeToFile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am doing the following when I get an image back from the server. But this code is bringing my app to its knees. It freezes up the UI.

Can this be run on a background thread in iOS? Can I use async?

```
 if (![NSString isEmpty:user.avatarURL])
 {
     NSString *pathToImage = user.avatarURL;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pathToImage];
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) forKey:kUserImage];

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                                                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userAvatar.png" ];
     NSData* jpegdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
     [jpegdata writeToFile:path atomically:YES];                                           
 }
```

Comment: I don't see why not to use `dispatch_async`. YES, you can use async

Comment: From your code it looks like you are not doing any thing on UI part, so you can easily execute this code in background.You can use dispatch_queues for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @valentin says, you can do everything inside the if() statement in a dispatch_async() call.

Note I suspect what’s probably slowing you down is actually the `-dataWithContentsOfURL:`, not the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`, so you’ll want to make sure that’s inside your dispatch_async, not outside.

Also, I’m not clear why you’re decompressing the data into an image, then re-compressing it. You’re going to get artifacts doing this, and with most services the avatar image is going to be compressed anyhow.

I’d do the following:

```
if (user.avatarURL) 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSURL *const imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:user.avatarURL];
        if (!imageURL)
            return;
        NSData *const imageDdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        if (!imageDdata.length)
            return;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageDdata forKey:kUserImage];

        [imageDdata writeToFile:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).lastObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userAvatar.png"] atomically:YES];                                           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The line which is doing most damage is:

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Because it does the download from the network. Nothing in your code updates the UI so it can all be run on a background thread. Just ensure that if you post a notification or subsequently update the UI after the image is saved that you switch back to the main thread.